# How to set > as a variable in bat

Tags: batch-file, escaping, cmd, var

Im wanting to be able to print this line to a file:
 
`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %ZOEXT%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%ZOEXT%">NUL`

But its proving to be difficult, to try and make it work properly i tried splitting it up considerably. I eventually got down to this

```
set TASKER=task
echo %TASKER%
pause
set PROPTASKLIST=%TASKER%list /FI "IMAGENAME eq
echo %PROPTASKLIST%
pause
set POINT=">
set POINT=%POINT:"=%
echo %POINT%
pause
set NULLER=NUL
echo %NULLER%
pause
set TONULL=%POINT%%NULLER%
echo %TONULL%
pause

set F=f
echo %F%
echo set F=f >> boot.bat
set FIND=%| %F% ind %/I %/N
echo %FIND%
echo %PROPTASKLIST% %%ZOEXT%%" 2%TONULL% %FIND% "%%ZOEXT%%"%TONULL% >> boot.bat
```

The "| FIND" doesn't seem to work, and all my attempts to set ">NUL" to anything has proved fruitless.

Current attempt was to set it to "">" which doesn't kill cmd, and then strip the character out later. But that made it crash anyway (or maybe im doing character stripping badly)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just don't know how to escape things. Try this:

```
echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%ZOEXT%%" 2^>NUL ^| find /I /N "%%ZOEXT%%"^>NUL>>boot.bat
```